# Call single object from Json file

Tags: java, json

I am learning how to implement Json in my project and have this Json file:

```js
{
   "stations":[
      {
         "station":"no1",
         "temperature":"xx",
         "windchill":"yy"
      },
      {
         "station":"no2",
         "temperature":"xx",
         "windchill":"yy"
      },
      {
         "station":"no2",
         "temperature":"xx",
         "windchill":"yy"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am able to succesfully display all values in a TextView, but I am only interested in lets say station no1. How do I pass the values from only station no1 in a textView?

This is my Json code:

```js
 try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(contents);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("stations");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject stations = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String station = stations.getString("station");
                    String temperature = stations.getString("temperature");
                    String temperature = stations.getString("windchill");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Once you finish this part, you should look at `RecyclerView` so that you can display a list of all the stations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject stations = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    String station = stations.getString("station");
    String temperature = stations.getString("temperature");
    String temperature = stations.getString("windchill");
}
```

You can do

```
JSONObject stations = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String station = stations.getString("station");
String temperature = stations.getString("temperature");
String temperature = stations.getString("windchill");
```

This way you will only get the values of the first element in your JSON.

Comment: Now I understand the for line. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Intead of using loop to all array length, **get only first object details** like below :

```
try {
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(contents);
  JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("stations");

  JSONObject stations = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

  String station = stations.getString("station");
  String temperature = stations.getString("temperature");
  String temperature = stations.getString("windchill");

} catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
```